# Can composite material be used in leading edge of airfoil instead of aluminium through Additive manufacturing?

Tags: airfoil

I want to know about, is it possible to replace aluminium by additively manufactured leading edge of airfoil by changing different infill patterns to improve the impct strength from bird impact on it.

Comment: The title and the subject seem to be asking slightly different questions here.  What do you mean by "composite material"? Carbon fiber composite?  What do you mean by "additively manufactured"? Laser powder bed fusion?  Are you proposing to replace an traditional aluminum lead edge with an AM leading edge?  or replace an aluminum leading edge with a carbon fiber composite edge?

Answer (score 3):

Lots of aircraft use composite material for their leading edges.

There is no need to use additive manufacturing to accomplish this.

That said, you might be interested in filament winding, automated tape laying, and automated fiber placement machines.